# How can recognize post's category?

Tags: plugins, categories, page-template, template-redirect

I want my plugin to recognize post's categories before post is loaded. i wrote this code but it works in category page not in post's page with the category is  specified from me.

```
function checkUser() {
    if(is_category('programming')){//it doesn't work when post with "programming" category is being displayed
            echo "Bingo!";
        include_once ('TEMPLATEPATH/get-messages.php');
        exit();
    }
} 
add_action('template_redirect', 'checkUser');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_single()` is intend to work with post types, not categories.

To check for category you should use `is_category('programming')`.

Note that `is_category` works on category archives, not on single view.

So, if you want to check in the current is a single view and has the category 'programming' you need the `has_term` tag:

```
if( is_single() && has_term('programming', 'category', get_queried_object()) ) {
  include_once ('TEMPLATEPATH/get-messages.php');
  exit();
}
```

See [is_single](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single), [is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) and [has_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) on Codex.

Also have a look on how [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) works in WP.

Comment: Oh sorry I've forgotten I wrote is_category('programming') but it works when i click on programming category not in post with 'programming' catgory. (let me edit my question)

Comment: for example I've a 'Qt' post with 'programming'category  and with this code it will be displayed when you click on it

Comment: @user1695063 see the edit

Comment: you're welcome @user1695063